# check if integers are in order condition jquery

Tags: jquery, sorting

Hi still getting my head around jQuery.  I'm fairly new to it and learning each day.   I'm more used to javascript because you know what's happening step by step.

Even though jQuery is "write less, do more"  the functions aren't clearly explained and I find it quite confusing.

Anyway my question...I have a sortable function where there are 7 numbers randomly listed.  In this case, 7,1,6,2,3,5,4...An user can drag the numbers in any order they wish..  I would like jQuery to fire an alert to say "well Done" when the user matches .sortable "#list" numbers in the right order.

I know there's elements of javascript in the jQuery code.  Not sure what the jQuery equivalent would be?

Thanks.

Html:

```
 <ul id="list" class="inline-list no-bullet">
                            <li>7</li>
                            <li>1</li>
                            <li>6</li>
                            <li>2</li>
                            <li>3</li>
                            <li>5</li>
                            <li>4</li>
   </ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#list").sortable({

                revert: true,
                containment: 'parent',
                update: function (event, ui) {

                    alert("List updated");
                }

                var orderedList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

                    for (i = 0; i <list.length; i++)
                       {
                             if (orderedList[i] == "list"[i]) 
                        {
                             alert('Well Done!');

                }

            });


        });
```

Comment: Just because you use jQuery you are not obligated to do everything via jQuery.

Comment: `var "trueOrder" = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];` ?

Comment: Sorry I meant orderedList

Comment: var "orderedList" is not right either. You do not declare vars as strings.  should be var orderedList no quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of issues there:

- when declaring variables don't use quotes (`var "trueOrder" = ...`): `var trueOrder = [1, 2, 3]`.
- `orderedList` is supposed to be `trueOrder`
- when accessing variables, don't use quotes: `"list"[i]` but `list[i]` (unless you want to access an object key value: `window["some_global"]`).

---

See the fixed code below.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $list = $("#list");
    $list.sortable({
        revert: true,
        containment: 'parent',
        update: function (event, ui) {
            var trueOrder = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
            var isFine = true;
            var list = $.map($list.children(), function (c) {
                return parseInt($(c).text());
            });
            
            for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                if (trueOrder[i] !== list[i]) {
                    isFine = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            
            if (isFine) {
                alert("Well done!");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list" class="inline-list no-bullet">
    <li>7</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you.  You took your time to explain where I went wrong and corrected me accordingly.

Comment: @Superunknown Hope you learn something from my post. You're welcome!